# LCOW deprecated - Windows server 2019 should now use Docker Desktop instead of Docker Entreprise?

Tags: docker, docker-desktop, windows-server-2019, lcow

Since v20.10 Docker has deprecated the use of LCOW, therefore the opportunity to run both Linux & WIndows containters on Windows Server has been restrcited.

As they state :

> The experimental feature to run Linux containers on Windows (LCOW) was
> introduced as a technical preview in Docker 17.09. While many
> enhancements were made after its introduction, the feature never
> reached completeness, and development has now stopped in favor of
> running docker natively on Linux in WSL2.
>
> Developers who want to run Linux workloads on a Windows host are encouraged to use Docker Desktop with WSL2 instead.

Does that means, that **on production** we are encouraged to migrate from DockerEE to Docker Desktop? It seems like a step backwards, isn't it?
Many thanks in advance.